# Xcode Testing - Followed Code from Docs but Getting Errors

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, testing

I am new to XCode and testing, and have followed the steps outlined in the iPhone Development Guide under "Unit Testing Applications".

I added a unit-test bundle to my project, named it "LogicTests", set it as the active target, then added a sample "LogicTests" unit-test class under a new group called "Tests".  I wrote the simple one-line test from the doc (`STFail(@"Must fail to succeed");`), then tried to build my project.

I keep getting the errors: `Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1` and `/Developer/Tools/RunPlatformUnitTests.include:448: error: Failed tests for architecture 'i386' (GC OFF)`.

The second error looks like the test is being run and failing properly, but the first error I am completely clueless about... What could the problem be here?

Thanks,
-Greta

Comment: Just a question for clarification: you wrapped that STFail statement in a method, did you?

Answer (score 1):

Well this behavior is totally normal. If the unit test failed it will produce a return code of 1. Test the opposite with STTrue(1,@"some message") and it should not return 1 and finish sucessfully.

Answer (score 0):

The test thinks your compiling for Intel not ARM architecture. Unfortunately, I can't remember off the top of my head how to set up the target properly.

Comment: That's normal. The unit test binary runs on your mac, not the iPhone, so it needs to be compiled for a 386 architecture.

Comment: Yeah, and I would have got that if I had paid attention to which testing framework he was using. *Sigh*